# How do I define a custom style for a button, but have different text/content display for each button?

Tags: wpf, xaml

So I have a style, below, that I want to apply to multiple buttons in my form (WPF). But each button needs to have a different caption, and I can't figure out to apply the same style to each one without copying + pasting + renaming for each one (and setting the content in the Textblock).

XAML in App.xaml

```
<Style x:Key="RunReportButton"
               TargetType="{x:Type Button}" 
               BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid Background="#EEB4B4">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBorder"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                                            To="#d6a2a2"
                                                            Duration="0:0:00.0" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBorder"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                        To="#d6a2a2"
                                        Duration="0:0:00.0" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border>
                            <Border.Background>
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Name="ButtonBorder" 
                                Color="Transparent" />
                            </Border.Background>
                        </Border>
                        <TextBlock 
                                   FontFamily="Open Sans"
                                   FontSize="16"
                                   FontWeight="SemiBold"
                                   Foreground="#CD3333"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Binding in my form:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource RunReportButton}"
                    Margin="0,20"/>
```

Comment: use `ContentPresenter` instead of `TextBlock` in template and set `FontFamily`, etc via Style Setters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the `TextBlock` in the `ControlTemplate`, use a `ContentPresenter`. By default it will display the `Content` property of the templated parent -- the button in your case. You could name a different property of the templated parent by setting `ContentPresenter.ContentSource`, but in this case the default is correct.

A `TextBlock` is a poor choice for that role because all it can display is a string, but `Button.Content` could be anything -- an `Image`, a `DataGrid`, a viewmodel, anything. No reason not to preserve that full range of possibilities.

There was an error in your original template: `<ControlTemplate>` was missing `TargetType="Button"`, which is critical for the template to function properly.

```
<Style 
    x:Key="RunReportButton"
    TargetType="{x:Type Button}" 
    BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}"
    >
    <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="Open Sans" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#EEB4B4" />
    <!-- Ditto for other TextElement.FontSize etc. -->

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBorder"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                                    To="#d6a2a2"
                                                    Duration="0:0:00.0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBorder"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                        To="#d6a2a2"
                                        Duration="0:0:00.0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border>
                        <Border.Background>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Name="ButtonBorder" 
                        Color="Transparent" />
                        </Border.Background>
                    </Border>
                    <!-- Ditto for other TextElement.FontSize etc. -->
                    <ContentPresenter
                        TextElement.FontFamily="{TemplateBinding TextElement.FontFamily}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                        Margin="5,5,5,5"
                        />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Also, if you use TemplateBindings as shown, you can set defaults for those properties in your Button style, and let the consumer override them in the XAML if he chooses.

Comment: I definitely like this approach the most...but I'm still not having the content appear at all, unless I explicitly define the Content property in the style

Comment: How are you giving the button its content?

Comment: I was planning on just setting it in the XAML of the window itself.

Comment: `<Button Style="{StaticResource RunReportButton}" Content="Blah" />`, like that?

Comment: Yes exactly like that.

Comment: @MichaelHolvey OHHHH I got it. `<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">`.

Comment: @MichaelHolvey Once I add `TargetType="Button"` to the `ControlTemplate` element the `ContentPresenter` can work properly.

Answer (score 0):

1. For each button, set the `Content` property to whatever text you want.
2. Set the `TextBlock`'s `Text` property to `{TemplateBinding Content}`. This markup extension binds one-way to the specified `DependencyProperty` of the item to which the `ControlTemplate` belongs.

Comment: So I can't set the TextBlock's Text property to that because the "member Content is not recognized or inaccessible". Did I not set the DependencyProperty appropriately?

Comment: @MichaelHolvey *""member Content is not recognized or inaccessible""* would have been due to the missing TargetType. All is now clear!